# SharePoint Online - BCC for external sharing invitations?

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

I'm new to SharePoint Online (and SharePoint in general) and have a question about external sharing.

We are using SharePoint Online via our O365 subscription.

We have some documents that we wanted to make available to multiple suppliers who would use those documents to formulate their bids.

Sharing was set up by right clicking on the document folder, selecting sharing and then putting in the email addresses of all the people we wanted to share with.

This worked OK but one of our suppliers commented that they could see all the other people who had been invited by looking at the **To:** field.

So my question is, can we get external sharing invitations to use BCC when sending e-mails instead?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible to *move* the shared recipients to BCC, however you can *add* email addresses to BCC through the SPO PowerShell cmdlets [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161390.aspx).

Setting the  `BccExternalSharingInvitations` parameter to `$true` and providing a list of email addresses to `BccExternalSharingInvitationsList` should satisfy your requirement

Example:
`Set-SPOTenant -BccExternalSharingInvitationsList "jim@email.com" -BccExternalSharingInvitations $true`